# WMI vs psutil for benchmarking CPU

Tags: python-3.x, windows, wmi, psutil

I am using three methods for getting CPU usage of windows machine:

1. psutil with interval of 1 sec:

   `cpu_usage=psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)`
2. psutil with interval of 10 sec:

   `cpu_usage=psutil.cpu_percent(interval=10)`
3. WMI package:

   `c = wmi.WMI()
   query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor where name='_Total'
   cpu_usage=c.query(query)[0].PercentUserTime`

"`

There is different of approximately 30% between the measurements;
I would like to know the advantage and disadvantages of each way, and which of those is most accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamental to understanding CPU measurement variability is an understanding of both Windows clock ticks (which form the basis of measurements) and logical CPUs (which are being measured active or idle in any given tick), and the way that the methods you describe perform the calculations.

The default Windows clock frequency is 64 ticks per second, or 15.625 milliseconds per tick.  If you were to look at the incrementing tick counters in the WMI table `Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor` (the raw data that the table you reference above draws from in its calculations) you would see them incrementing in multiples of 156250 (100-nanosecond ticks).  The large number of nanoseconds gives a false sense of precision, when in reality, each processor can be off by one tick at both the beginning and end of each measurement interval by up to 1/64 of a second.

So your elapsed time for what you think as one second could be as short as 62/64 seconds or as long as 66/64 seconds, a +/- 3.125% inaccuracy.  Not that big a deal, but one would probably prefer a 10 second interval with a +/- 0.3125% range.

This lack of precision is a bigger issue for the numerator, however, as you don't have the full second to work with.  The ticks are split between user, system, and idle *for each logical processor*.  Consider, for example, a quad-core system with hyperthreading using 25% CPU, split 12.5% system, 12.5% user, and 75% idle.  You have eight logical processors.  During the 1/4 of a second that each processor is active, only 16 clock ticks elapse, 8 ticks in system mode and 8 in user mode.  But you could be under or over by 2 clock ticks if you picked the wrong start and end times, a range of 6 to 10 ticks for each of the 8 logical processors.  So if you added up ticks for the whole system, you'd get from 48 to 80 ticks vs. the expected 64, a potential error of up to +/- 25%.  Two independent measurements in identical circumstances could be off from each other by up to 50%.   Want to add "user+system" for overall CPU usage?  Up to 100% difference in successive measurements.   Of course these are worst case extremes, the actual error will be smaller, and if you averaged all the errors after a long time, they'd net out to zero.

Now, as regards your methods in your question:

1 and 2: `psutil.cpu_percent` calls [GetSystemTimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getsystemtimes) under the hood. This has an advantage over WMI methods in that you don't get the additional error involved in summing results.  However, realize that you're getting the "cumulative total time since the computer started" for these values.  A system bouncing between 10% and 30% usage will give you a calculation of about 20% every time with little change.   In order to measure CPU usage across shorter time frames, you need to save the result from the previous call, and then measure the differences over the elapsed time.  (You should also sum the elapsed ticks to use as the elapsed time, to avoid further inaccuracies.)  In this case, a longer interval for the calculation will reduce the errors, although you could certainly do a rolling calculation (e.g., poll every 1 second but use a 10-second historical value for the usage).

3: The WMI `_Total` instance just sums up the individual logical processor values so has that increased lack of precision (worse the more processors you have) vs. the system-based method in 1 and 2.  Additionally, the  "Formatted" data is based on the "Raw" data in a similarly named table, with the elapsed time based on your sample interval.  This means the very first sample will give you results similar to the cumulative-since-start usage in the first method, but later samples will either give you unchanged data (if your interval is too short) or the "current" usage since the last sample.  In addition to this relative lack of control of the calculation using "Formatted" data (that you could overcome by manually calculating "Raw" data) WMI also has the disadvantage of the COM overhead to query the performance counters (sometimes very slow for the first query), while the `psutil` method is a direct native system call and much faster to use repeatedly.

In summary: for total system time, you're best off using the `psutil` values, but doing your own calculation based on the differences between successive measurements at a polling interval that you choose. Longer intervals give more accurate measurements but less ability to measure spikes in usage.

WMI gives you more insight into per-processor usage, but at a tradeoff for overhead in exchange for ease of query.  If you really want this usage, you might want to get it directly from the system performance counters (which is where WMI ultimately gets them).